# Proving an inequality by manipulating both sides

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

When proving an inequality, is it valid to manipulate both sides of the expression simultaneously (subtracting and adding terms from each side) and then arriving at a statement that must be true. For example if I manipulate both sides and arrive at $|a| \geq 0$ then I can conclude the proof? Or must I manipulate each side independently?

Comment: If each operation is invertible, then yes you can. This is because you could always start with the resulting true statement and work "backwards" to get to the given form of the inequality.

Answer (score 0):

When you are solving equations you have to understand the difference between necessity and sufficiency. Typically when we solve an equation we begin by assuming that the equation has a solution, and then manipulating the equation until it tells us what that solution must be.

For example, if I were to start with the equation $$4-x<x$$ I can add $x$ to both sides and then divide each side by $2$, giving $$2<x.$$ Because I have arrived at this equation by a process of deduction, I know that any $x$ solving the first equation ($4-x<x$) must also solve the second equation ($x<2$). This second statement is necessary. But technically, we have not proven it is sufficient. That is, we have not proven any that if $x<2$ then we will be guaranteed that $4-x<x.$ To get sufficiency, you have to be able to start with the result ($x<2$) and then work backward to get $4-x<x$. This can be done if each operation in your calculation is invertible (can be done backwards).

As an example of where necessity and sufficiency disagree, suppose I started with the equation $x^3>0$. Squaring both sides, I get $x^6>0.$ This equation is satisfied whenever $x\neq 0.$ But supposing that $x=-1$, we have that $$x^3<0.$$ What went wrong?

The equation $x\neq 0$ was necessary, but not sufficient to guarantee that $x^3>0.$ When I squared both sides, I was using an operation that could not be done backwards and so I lost sufficiency.

My example might seem highly contrived, but there are situations in math where the difference between necessity and sufficiency can become a real issue and it is important to understand exactly what you are saying. So let this post be a warning. Necessity and sufficiency are not the same thing.